# Getting Module not found: Can't resolve '...' in '...' error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a component for my sidebar in the sidebar folder and tried to import that component in `app.js`  using `import Sidebar from './components/sidebar/Sidebar'`. But I m getting the following error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '.Sidebar.css' in 'D:\Programming\dashboard\telehealth\src\components\sidebar'
```

Here is the comment code:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css'
import Sidebar from './components/sidebar/Sidebar'
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container-fluid bg-sucss">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="sidebar col-md-2 bg-dark text-light">
            <Sidebar />
          </div>
          <div className="rightside col-md-10 flex-column">
            
              <div className="row header bg-info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo expedita optio iusto.</div>
              <div className="row content bg-danger">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est doloribus beatae aliquid similique!</div>
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I think the problem is inside the Sidebar component where you imported Sidebar.css. Can you paste what is inside the Sidebar component? If you are importing it, try to change URL to this `./Sidebar.css` if it is inside sidebar folder.

Comment: The problem may be in the place where you are importing the `sidebar.css`.. It looks like you missed the slash `/` while importing it.. Check whether the path is right and you add slash in front like `./Sidebar.css` .. From the error it gives the issue is under sidebar component only and not in `App` .. So check sidebar component..

Comment: @AbdurRehmanKhalid, Change `import '.Sidebar.css'` to `import './Sidebar.css'` .. Make note of slash **/** ..

Answer (score 0):

Here is where you are doing it wrong : `import '.Sidebar.css'`. Do as below  instead, if `Sidebar.css` is in the same folder as `Sidebar.js`:

```
import './Sidebar.css'
```